# I have a problem with json variable setting

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

i have this code here:

```
import json
with open("pass_file.txt", "r") as file:
    password = json.loads(file.read())
```

it calls this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testdoc.py", line 9, in <module>
print(json.loads(file.read()))
File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I dont know why this is happening because i have the same code on another file just with different variable name and file name and it works file. I did notice another similar question about a similar error but it didnt answer my question.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what is the contents of *pass_file.txt* ? the problem is in it, there is no way for us to help you if you do not give it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the content of you pass_file.txt ? The python code use `json.loads` so it expect JSON formated content in the pass_file.txt
For example for a string, the content of this file will be `"hello world"`
If you don't put quotes, the JSON parsing process will fail.

Comment: Thanks. It was the quotes i was forgetting in the file. It works with them. I guess I just assumed it would be a string but appears not.